# Performance of get_json_object vs. from_json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm am curious as to how Spark operates with the `get_json_object` method, and whether I am using it correctly. Say I have a column `data` of type string (JSON-encoded), with the value of each row rather large in size (~1MB).

If I want to retrieve and process a subset of the parameters, I could easily do:

```py
param_a = get_json_object("data", "$.my.param.a").cast("int")
param_b = get_json_object("data", "$.my.param.b").cast("int")

my_sum = param_a + param_b
```

Will Spark automagically derive that it only needs to decode the JSON internally once, and then re-use that state, or will it decode for every call to `get_json_object`?

---

Alternatively I could once use `from_json` and retrieve in a well-defined schema:

```py
_schema = StructType().add("a", IntegerType()).add("b", IntegerType())
params = from_json(get_json_object("data", "$.my.param"), _schema)

my_sum = params["a"] + params["b"]
```

So my question is: **Are these methods comparable in performance, and/or are there other reasons to use one approach over the other?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of this part of Apache Spark is pretty limited, but wanted to share a bit on the code of `get_json_object` that could shed more light (and perhaps lead to a much helpful answer).

---

**tl;dr**: I'd recommend using `from_json(get_json_object(...), ...)` when multiple JSON fields are accessed to avoid more expensive `get_json_object`s (memory-wise).

(I'm using Scala, but that does not really matter here except that it's closer to "bare metal")

```
// let's use a very simple query to demo the concept
val q = sql("""SELECT get_json_object('{"a":"b"}', '$.a'), get_json_object('{"aa":"bb"}', '$.aa')""")
scala> q.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [b AS get_json_object({"a":"b"}, $.a)#10, bb AS get_json_object({"aa":"bb"}, $.aa)#11]
+- *(1) Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

As you may have noticed, the physical query plan uses two distinct `get_json_object` expressions (one with `#10` and the other with `#11` unique identifiers).

`get_json_object` is simply [GetJsonObject](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9b8fd3425ced975e7e469e5bbbef61dca631b31f/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L122) Catalyst expression under the covers and [eval](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9b8fd3425ced975e7e469e5bbbef61dca631b31f/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L140-L175) method is where all the magic happens.

At some point `eval` does `CreateJacksonParser.utf8String(jsonFactory, jsonStr)`. That uses this `jsonFactory` value which happens to be shared across any Java/Python/Scala/JVM code since it's a `val` and part of [object SharedFactory](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9b8fd3425ced975e7e469e5bbbef61dca631b31f/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L102-L108). In Scala, the keyword `object`  gives a single instance across all tasks on an Spark executor (a single JVM). That's certainly shared instance, but that's a mere factory (not a JSON parser itself).

My understanding is that every time a new JSON parser is requested, a new one is created (perhaps because it's a mutable "beast"?). You'd have to review Jackson's [JsonFactoryBuilder](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonFactoryBuilder.java) to find out.

Answer (score 2):

So I wrote a test ([Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/casparjespersen/99506c648f872ed7b1b97bcfcdcb41f9)) to test it out. Basically a setup doing what I described above, with the following variables:

- Number of parameters to decode
- Number of rows
- Size of each data row
- Number of replications/experiments to average over

Using 8 parameters across 100 rows with 1KB data JSON-encoded string content (and 500 replications), these are the results:

```
{<function _method_b at 0x7fb73d30e200>: 0.16155768394470216,
 <function _method_a at 0x7fb73d30e320>: 0.22132105827331544}
```

Hence, it appears for this scenario there is an improvement on enforcing schema of around 25%.

Furthermore:

- Decreasing the amount of parameters from 8 to 2 did in fact squander the difference:

```
{<function _method_b at 0x7f43d7dc4200>: 0.15471874809265138,
 <function _method_a at 0x7f43d7dc4320>: 0.14935027599334716}
```

Therefore: I would conclude that if you want to interpret many parameters of a structure, there is a performance improvement of enforcing schema, but if it's just a few it could be just as performant (and easier to read/write) to just use `get_json_object` and casting.